# Connect Four Check Winner

Tags: c, connect-four

So to change my question. It refuses to recognize that there are four twos in a row. It recognizes that there are four ones in a row but that happens after the four twos. Why is this happening?

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 2 2 2 2 0 0

```
int checkFour(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    if (a == b == c == d){
        return 1;
    }
    
    else{
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

//check for the horizontal win
int checkHorizontal(){
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < column - 3; j++){
            if ((board[i][j] != 0) && (board[i][j+1] != 0) && (board[i][j+2]!= 0) && (board[i][j+3] != 0)){
                if (checkFour(board[i][j],board[i][j+1],board[i][j+2],board[i][j+3]) == 1){
                printf("Game Over\n");
                exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't "change"  your question. It is not a conversation that we are supposed to follow. Make it a new question with all of the background information.

Comment: `if (a == b == c == d){` Does not work the way you might think it does. `if (a == b && a == c && a == d){`

Comment: `if (a == b == c == d)` ... ouch! C is not math. The expression `a==b` is equal to 0 or 1, then this value (0 or 1) is compared with `c`, which again is 0 or 1, which finally is compared with `d`.

Answer (score 1):

`if (a == b == c == d){` does not work the way you might think. The result of a comparison in C is a boolean value of `0` or `1`.  Given that `==` operator has left-to-right associativity, your statement can be re-written as:

```
if ((((a == b) == c) == d)
```

This appears to give correct results when they are all `1`. This is because it ends up comparing the values (1) to the result of the comparison operation, also (1).

```
(((a == b) == c) == d)   a == b -> 1
((1 == c) == d)          1 == c -> 1
(1 == d)                 1 == d -> 1
```

The correct way is to use logical AND.

```
if (a == b && a == c && a == d)
```

All three comparisons need to evaluate to `true` for the entire statement to be `true`.

Note that there are other combinations that work. Ex:

```
if (a == b && b == c && c == d)
```

By the way, you can shorten the entire function to

```
int checkFour(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    return a == b && b == c && c == d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you misunderstood the mechanism of C. the code `if (a == b == c == d)` wouldn't take if abcd are all values equal then `return 1`. because C computes from left to right(*same priority*), so it would compute  `a == b` first, the result is 1 or 0, then take this result to compare with `c`, the second result also is 1 or 0, finally take second result to compare with `d` and the final result is come out. 
The right code is like this:

```
if ((a == b) && (d == c) && (b == c))
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```